# How can I passs a method except parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, listener, android-viewmodel

I hope to pass a method which implement `MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener`.

At present I use Code A to pass the  method which implement `MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener`.

Is there any other way to do it? maybe just like Code B.

**Code A**

```
class HomeViewModel(...) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {

    fun startRecord() {
        startRecord(savedfilename){
             mr, what, extra ->
                 if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                     stopRecord()
                 }            
        }

    }

}


class RecordService : Service() {  

    fun startRecord(filename:String, mOnInfoListener: MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener){
       mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mRecorder?.let {    
            with(it) {                  
                setOnInfoListener(mOnInfoListener)    
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

**Code B**

```
class HomeViewModel(...) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {

{
    //I save  mOnInfoListener to memory ?   
    val mOnInfoListener = object: MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener{
        mr, what, extra ->
           if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
              stopRecord()
          }
    }

    fun startRecord() {
        startRecord(savedfilename)    
    }

}


class RecordService : Service() {  

    fun startRecord(filename:String){
       mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mRecorder?.let {    
            with(it) {
                setOnInfoListener(mOnInfoListener)  //  I get mOnInfoListener from memory ?    
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to change Code B to make it compile?

Comment: Thanks!  I  hope to pass `MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener` from `class HomeViewModel(...)` to `class RecordService()` without using parameter.  Code B is my ideas, and I don't know whether it's correct, or is there the more better way  without using parameter just like Code A?

Comment: You could do it with dependency injection but it’s poor design to couple in both directions when you don’t need to. You could use a top level property or put in a singleton object, but that’s even worse. It’s just not a good design pattern. Note that code A is fine and it *is* using a parameter. It’s using lambda syntax for that parameter, but it’s still a parameter. There are several other ways you could pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `Code A` looks good in terms of passing a lambda as parameter. But I would make a couple of improvements.

I would encapsulate the work with `MediaRecorder` in one class, e.g. `RecordService`, `HomeViewModel` doesn't need to know anything about what tools `RecordService` uses to make records. And if you need to react on recorder's events you can create an additional interface for that. The sample code with all interfaces and events will look like the following:

```
sealed interface Event
object MaxDurationReachedEvent : Event
//... create another events if need

interface RecordServiceEventListener {
    fun onRecordEvent(event: Event)
}

interface RecordService {
    fun startRecord(filename: String)
    fun registerEventListener(listener: RecordServiceEventListener)
    fun unregisterEventListener(listener: RecordServiceEventListener)

}

class RecordServiceImpl : Service(), RecordService {

    private var recorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    private var eventListeners: MutableList<RecordServiceEventListener> = mutableListOf()

    override fun startRecord(filename: String) {
        recorder = MediaRecorder()
        recorder?.setOnInfoListener { mr, what, extra ->
            if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                eventListeners.forEach { it.onRecordEvent(MaxDurationReachedEvent) }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun registerEventListener(listener: RecordServiceEventListener) {
        eventListeners.add(listener)
    }

    override fun unregisterEventListener(listener: RecordServiceEventListener) {
        eventListeners.remove(listener)
    }
}

class HomeViewModel(private val recordService: RecordService) : ViewModel(), RecordServiceEventListener {

    init {
        recordService.registerEventListener(this)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        recordService.unregisterEventListener(this)
    }

    fun startRecord() {
        recordService.startRecord(savedFilename)
    }

    override fun onRecordEvent(event: Event) {
        when (event) {
            MaxDurationReachedEvent -> { ... /* Do something */ }
        }
    }
}
```

It is better to work with interfaces rather than with concrete implementations. Also I wouldn't suggest to use `m` prefix when naming variables, it is a style of **Java** language, not **Kotlin**.

P.S. `Flow` can be used to emit events of a recorder instead of `RecordServiceEventListener`, but this is another story :)

Comment: Thanks, which prefix instead of `m`  should be used when naming variables if I use Kotlin. ?

Comment: Thanks!  is `recordService.registerEventListener(this)`  in `HomeViewModel` global  because `object MaxDurationReachedEvent : Event` is top event ?  so your code implement my Code B, right?

Comment: There are no prefixes in Kotlin style, except of Backing properties https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#naming_2.

Comment: `registerEventListener()` function is public, it can be called from any class through an instances of `RecordService` children, i.e. `RecordServiceImpl`. It's not exactly code B, but it is similar, my code uses a variable to store registered listeners and notify them of particular event. But still we register listeners by passing them as arguments into the function `registerEventListener(listener: RecordServiceEventListener)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
class HomeViewModel(...) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {
    //I save  mOnInfoListener to memory ?
    val mOnInfoListener = object : MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {
        override fun onInfo(mr: MediaRecorder, what: Int, extra: Int) {
            if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                stopRecord()
            }
        }
    }


    fun startRecord() {
        startRecord(savedfilename)
    }

}


class RecordService(private val mOnInfoListener: MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener) : Service() {

    fun startRecord(filename: String) {
        val mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(mOnInfoListener)  //  I get mOnInfoListener from memory ?
    }
}
```